# Error installing windows azure sdk for 64 bit OS - Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis-7, windows-7, azure

I tried installing Windows Azure SDK on Windows 7 Professional, with IIS 7.5, but failed. The system says,et

"To use this software you should enable windows internet information services 7.0 with Asp.Net support.See the product release notes for details"

I also got into framework 4.0 from the commmand prompt and ran aspnetregiis -i , but still it didn't work.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing via the Web Platform Installer (start at http://microsoft.com/web).  That does a good job of determining what (if any) dependencies you're missing.

If that doesn't help, try posting this over on the Windows Azure forum on MSDN (http://tinyurl.com/wazforum).  There the Windows Azure support folks can help.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't IIS that is the issue. You may need to enable ASP.NET in your IIS.

Read how to [enable ASP.NET in IIS 7.5 for Windows Azure SDK](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/06/azure-sdk-enable-iis-70-with-aspnet.html) here.